# Scroll to top of tab section not working on click using slideToggle

Tags: jquery

I have a simple 'tab' effect jQuery `slideToggle`, where the user clicks a heading `.expander-heading` and the `next()` div `.expander-content`, expands. I am sadly having some trouble offsetting/scrolling to the top of this `.expander-content` div on click, however.

```
$(".expander-heading").click(function () {

      $header = $(this);
      //getting the next element
      $content = $header.next();
      //open up or close
      $content.slideToggle(325);

      $(".site-container").animate({
        scrollTop: $content.offset().top
      }, "fast");

});
```

With an HTML structure like so:

```
<div class="expander-heading d-block u-pointer">
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="expander-content d-none">
    <p>Tabbed content</p>
</div>
```

In the above, I get the next item in the structure using `$content`, my on `click` function works fine, finding the next element in the page, but how come here on `.animate()`, `$content` can't be scrolled to the top of?

*I use `.site-container`rather than `html,body` because my main body div sits inside of its own div, where the body overflow is hidden.*

Pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGRPEW

Comment: a fiddle would help a lot. are you sure `.site-container` is the element that needs to be scrolled

Comment: Yes, Velimir. I used scrollTop at one point to take the user back to the top of the page on some pages, when I use html,body it does not work, when I use .site-container, it does work. Will our in a fiddle now.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGRPEW